# Intersection of 3 planes with linearly independent normals

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Tom Apostol's Calculus, vol. $1$, exercise $13.17.16$ is:

> Prove that three planes whose normals are linearly independent intersect in one and only one point.

We know that every $n$ linearly independent vectors form a basis of $V_n$ space, and the span each vector in $V_n$ uniquely. Therefore, in $V_3$ the solution is easy to prove, because the 3 normals are a basis in $V_3$.

However, it is not clear from the exercise statement that it asks only for planes in $V_3$, and to me it's not clear if it should hold in general.

Let $P$ be the point of intersection, and $N_1, N_2, N_3$ are the normals of the 3 planes, so we have:

$$
X_1 N_1 = P N_1 = p_1n_{11}+p_2n_{12}+p_3n_{13}+p_4n_{14} \\
X_2 N_2 = P N_2 \\
X_3 N_3 = P N_3
$$
$\tag{1}X = p_1N_{*1} + p_2N_{*2} + p_3N_{*3} + p_3N_{*4}$

Where $N_{*n}$ is a $3$-dimensional vector constructed from the $n$-th dimension of the original $N$ vectors (e.g. $N_{*1} = (n_{11}, n_{21}, n_{31})$), and  $X = (X_1N_1, X_2N_2, X_3N_3)$.

From ${1}$ it seems that there does not have to exist a unique solution (i.e. $P = (p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4)$), because the $4$ $N_{*n}$ vectors are not linearly independent in $V_3$.

Am I wrong about that?

Thanks!

---

Edit, as a comment asks for a clarification what the plane means: A plane is defined as a set of points $M$ such that $M = \{P + sA + tB | s, t \in R \}$, and $A, B$ are linearly independent vectors, and $P$ is a point on the plane.

Comment: First things first: what do you call a "plane" if $n\ne 3$? If you mean "subspace of dimension $n-1$ (what is normally called a "hyperplane"), then the statement is not true for $n>3$: the intersection will have more than one point. I wonder what your "easy to prove" solution for $n=3$ is.

Comment: Also I don't understand what you call $X, X_1, X_2, X_3$, and also what operation is used to multiply, say, $X_1$ with $N_1$. (It may be a convention in Apostol's. book, sorry I don't have it at hand, but many readers of your question won't either, so it would be good to edit your question to elaborate.)

Comment: Added the definition for the plane, as stated in Tom Apostol's book. $X_1N_1$ is the usual dot product.

Comment: Ah, thanks, but then I don't understand what you call a _normal_ of the plane. If it is a vector orthogonal to all the vectors in the plane, then the space of those vectors is of co-dimension $2$ (as for you the plane is of *dimension* $2$), so, let's say $n=4$: there isn't a unique (up to a constant) normal to the plane, but all the normal vectors make up a $2$-dimensional space!

Comment: I guess you're saying that the exercise question does not make sense for a space of dimensionality > 3, and that's why implicitly it's assumed that it's meant for $V_3$ only?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I agree with that, and thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Let's assume you are working over $\mathbb R$ and that $n>3.$ To avoid too many subsripts, we'll suppose that we have $n$ letters $a,b,...,\zeta$ and three hyper planes $a_ix_1+b_ix_2+...+\zeta_ix_n+\xi_i=0$ for$ i=1,2,3.$ If you look at the cefficient and augmened matrices for this set of three equations, you will see that they both have rank 3, so there is at least one solution. However if there are two solutions $$(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)$$ and $$(x_1^{**},...,x_n^{**})$$ we subtract and see that thedifference of the solutions is in the solution space of the coefficient matrix. The dimension of this soluion space is $n-3 \ge 1$ so the two solutions are not necessarily the same, ie. the point of intersection of the three hyperplanes is not unique.

Comment: I would refrain from answering before the OP clarifies what they mean. For one thing, they've now clarified that they call "planes" the affine *$2$-dimensional* subspaces (i.e. not $n-1$-dimensional subspaces a.k.a. hyperplanes).

OTOH they seem to be happy with your answer, so ... who knows ???!